# Ionic Cordova Network plugin error

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, network-connection, ionic-native

I'm trying to add a network connectivity listener to an ionic 2 app.

I followed the same steps as shown in the official website, but getting some error as shown in the image.

[image: Can not find module ionic-native]

One more thing that I noticed, a warning which appeared while I was installing the native plugins.

```
  ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/core@3.4.2
  └── @ionic-native/network@3.11.0 

  npm WARN @ionic-native/network@3.11.0 requires a peer of @ionic-
  native/core@^3.6.0 but none was installed.
```

I couldn't find anything so far. Anybody know what's going on in here!

Comment: Can you put your `package.json` here?

Answer (score 0):

did you install ionic network plugin:

```
npm install @ionic-native/network --save
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/network